# bash/python/perl/etc. Fast generation of file with many pairs of random, alphabetic strings

Tags: python, bash, perl, random, file-io

#### My Problem

I was surprised not to find a similar question here. Maybe I need to learn how to search better. Mainly, I'm trying to figure out which part of my algorithm is slow and if there are alternate, faster ways to accomplish my goal.

I am trying to generate a file with 100 million pairs of random, alphabetic strings. These random strings can include spaces. There are some real, fixed words around the random ones. An example of my desired output is

```
rrn TRY gy q OFTEN
ibh TRY mpdw OFTEN
bnq TRY nbjw OFTEN
tky TRY tedr OFTEN
c r TRY  fdv OFTEN
cvs TRY dusr OFTEN
ppd TRY qhrc OFTEN
...
```

I would like to be able to do this in a Linux scripting language (I'm actually using Cygwin), so answers in `bash`, `python`, `perl`, etc. would be preferred. However, if I'm going to get a big increase in speed using `C++`, `Java`, or something else, I'm open to that.

Currently, my script is run via

```
$ ./create_big_file.sh 100000000
```

The `bash` script is as follows. I have changed things so as not to hard-code the number of pairs.

**My Executable Code**

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# @file create_big_file.sh

n_lines=$1
filename="big_file_${n_lines}.out"

n_lett_rand_str1=3 # originally had 5, tried 3 for speed
n_lett_rand_str2=4 # originally had 10, tried 4 for speed

between=" TRY "
after=" OFTEN"

while [ $n -lt $n_lines ]; do
  n_lett_rand_str1=3
  n_lett_rand_str2=4

  random_str1=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-z ' | \
fold -w $n_lett_rand_str1 | head -n 1)

  random_str2=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-z ' | \
fold -w $n_lett_rand_str2 | head -n 1)

  echo "${random_str1}${between}${random_str2}${after}" >> "$filename"

  n=$(($n+1))

done #endof:  while [ $n -lt $n_lines ]
```

My run-rime scales approximately linearly, as expected, but the time taken for each iteration seems high to me. If I make the estimation of pure linear time, I've calculated that it would take 265.0 days. If I use the complete `t=a*exp[x,b]` fit, I've calculated 1.016 years. If I only wanted a million lines, it would take about 2-3 days.

**The Question**

I'm thinking there's got to be a way to do what I'm trying to do, but faster. Does anyone know of a way to create such a file in less time? I'd be willing to settle for 1 million lines if I could get it in less than 4 hours, but I hope to be able to get 100 million lines in less than a day.

P.S. This is not homework; I'm working on some text analysis.

---

#### My Research

```
$ time ./create_big_file.sh 10

real    0m2.487s
user    0m1.115s
sys     0m1.950s

$ time ./create_big_file.sh 100

real    0m22.356s
user    0m11.764s
sys     0m16.517s

$ tail -2 big_file_100.out
mri TRY nzeo OFTEN
hev TRY uqdf OFTEN

$ time ./create_big_file.sh 500

real    1m52.143s
user    0m57.347s
sys     1m19.405s

$ time ./create_big_file.sh 1000

real    3m50.129s
user    1m58.697s
sys     2m45.612s
```

The fit for time vs. number of lines, as found at [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FindFit%5B%7B%7B10.,2.478%7D,%7B100,22.356%7D,%7B500,112.143%7D,%7B1000,230.129%7D%7D,a*x%5Eb,%7Ba,b%7D,x%5D), is

*t(x) = 0.11905 x<sup>1.02845</sup>*

I tried replacing

```
random_str1=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-z ' | \
fold -w $n_lett_rand_str1 | head -n 1)
```

with

```
random_str1=$(echo $RANDOM | tr '[0-9]' '[a-z ]')
```

and made the same change to `random_str2`. That gave me two strings of up to 5 letters. However, I got no significant difference in run-time.

**Comparison**

I ran the script without any random generation of strings. I commented out anything that had to do with the random stuff and ran the while loop with just

```
echo "${between}${after}"
n=$(($n+1))
```

inside, and my runtime numbers were (format: `{n_lines, n_seconds}`)

```
{{10, 0.049},{100, 0.097},{500, 0.157},{1000,0.263}, {10000, 1.996}, {100000, 19.222}}
```

giving an order of growth as ([source](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FindFit%5B%7B%7B10,%200.049%7D,%7B100,%200.097%7D,%7B500,%200.157%7D,%7B1000,0.263%7D,%20%7B10000,%201.996%7D,%20%7B100000,%2019.222%7D%7D,a*x%5Eb,%7Ba,b%7D,x%5D))

*t(x) = 0.000243745 x<sup>0.979367</sup>*

That makes me pretty sure the random stuff is causing the problems - like 0.2 seconds per random problems.

**Edit**
The "random" doesn't have to be extremely random. I basically want it to not repeat on the order of 10-20 lines (except VERY rarely.) Again, it's for text processing things. Thanks to @zdim for asking for that clarification.

This will likely only be run once or twice in a six-month period.

Comment: Hi, I have rewritten bash scripts into Perl many times when bash was to slow.  The performance was greatly improved.  Then I will not comment on the algorithm itself, just the implementation language.  You can look at this https://blog.famzah.net/2016/02/09/cpp-vs-python-vs-perl-vs-php-performance-benchmark-2016/

Comment: Yes, the biggest consumer would be the "random stuff," and with all those extra processes (pipeline!).  The next consumer would be the I/O, and finally I suspect the choice of shell.  So: try with some dirt simple randomness (important: how good does that need to be?). And use a different tool.  Given what you desire I'd say that a scripting language should do, but of course that C/C++ should be better.  Also: can you precompute a quasi-random sequence? Does this need to run repeatedly, often ...?

Comment: I just rewrote it in Perl and it took about 3 seconds to create 100_000_000 lines with 3 and 4.

Comment: @zdim : Thanks for your helpful comments. I did find a solution using a quasi-random sequence. (I replaced `cat` with `base64`, wrote two arrays of 1 million strings, then read them back out.) This worked, but took over 20 minutes. I seem to remember that `bash` has an array-size limit based on underlying RAM. [This link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/195215/291375) says 1.3 GB ram leads to a limit of about 18 million. @simbabque has a solution that is much faster, but you're welcome to post your idea as an answer for completeness.

Comment: @zdim : I also have a n00b question. What do you mean by "pipeline!"?

Comment: I think I figured out what is meant by "pipeline!". As I understand it, each time a pipe is used, a subshell is spawned. Is this correct?

Comment: Right. By a "pipeline" one normally refers to a string of  pipes `|` taking a command's output and making it another command's input.  This is a quintessential UNIX approach, of combining tools, each designed to do their thing, for complete processing.  However, for each `|` a subshell need be spawned and this costs.

Comment: I appreciate you letting me know that I had figured it out correctly. Your help has been great!

Comment: I'm wondering why this question has been voted down. I'm planning on removing the question, since it seems like it's not a good question. However, I'd like to know why it got the negative responses.

Comment: After looking at meta stuff [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270586/6505499) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291139/6505499) I decided to leave the question here. Considering its reach, it doesn't seem too consequential whether it stays or not. Also, considering the reputation gained by @simbabque , deleting this wouldn't hurt...I just hate to get rid of such an awesome answer.

Comment: @bballdave025 Yes, please leave it -- it's a good question!  I've no idea why it got downvoted -- perhaps because it's long, written in proper sentences, with some unneeded statements here or there ... ?  I voted it up back then and i reread it  now and still think that it's a (very) good question.  It could be simplified and shortened but those are details which don't make it bad (just harder to read through).

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to comment on this, @zdim. I also appreciate the help you gave when I was facing the issue. Keep up the good work!

Comment: You are most welcome :)   Thanks for responding :)

Comment: Thank you for the nice words. It's at 0 now. No idea why I didn't vote at the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in Perl and it will run in a matter of seconds for 100 million lines.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

# read command line arguments
my ( $first_length, $second_length, $lines, $first_word, $second_word ) = @ARGV;
$first_word //= 'TRY';
$second_word //= 'OFTEN';

# define your alphabet of random characters
my @alphabet = ( 'a' .. 'z', q{ } );
my $max_rand = scalar @alphabet;

foreach my $i ( 1 .. $lines ) {
    say join(
        q{ },
        ( join q{}, map { $alphabet[ int rand $max_rand ] } 1 .. $first_length ),
        $first_word,
        ( join q{}, map { $alphabet[ int rand $max_rand ] } 1 .. $second_length ),
        $second_word,
    );
}
```

This program takes three or five arguments:

```
$ perl foo.pl 3 4 100000000 TRY OFTEN
```

On my machine it took about three seconds to generate the full 100M lines. The output looks like this:

```
wab TRY mcqb OFTEN
tdb TRY tobw OFTEN
rlf TRY lg v OFTEN
ofn TRY oxdf OFTEN
o j TRY vcfp OFTEN
ffv TRY doud OFTEN
lvl TRY ckci OFTEN
xqh TRY wnaa OFTEN
fhj TRY  pmp OFTEN
oxe TRY swyi OFTEN
```

Comment: Verified! I ran it for a million strings to compare with my `bash` array solution (which couldn't get to 100 million due to array-size issues.) Input: `time perl foo.pl 3 4 1000000 > big_file.out` Output: `real  0m3.170s` `user 0m3.135s` `sys 0m0.015s`. My computer is obviously slower that yours, but the solution is excellent!

Comment: @bballdave025 yeah that's the problem with benchmarking. ;)